# How do I make a JLabel that has an imageIcon that is available to all methods and classes?

Tags: java, swing

I want to have an ImageIcon in a JLabel that i will be able to update from another method. But I can't figure out a way to be able to create a static JLabel(so as to be able to acccess it from another method) and also instaiate it as a Jlabel that contains an imageIcon - is there another method other than JLabel label = new JLabel(imgIcon) to create a label with an imageIcon? tried to use the setIcon method without the label being instatiated the way it is above but it gave a null pointer exception. Thanks in adavance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make the JLabel static - instead define it outside of other methods but still in your class.

```
public class Test {

    private JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(/*your icon*/));
}
```

If you need to access it from another class, create an accessor method:

```
public JLabel getLabel() {
    return label;
}
```

Comment: If the label is created private can I access it form other methods in the same class if it was created outside of any method? Because I am getting an error that tells me that a non-static variable cannot be referenced froma static context? Does this mean tnhat even for within the same class I have to use the getlabel(0 method? If so how do I use the getlabel() method? do i need to create a label to call the getLabel method from ie label2 = test.getLabel()? or how do I get access to it to change the Icon in the label? thanks

Comment: Don't make your methods static if you want access from other methods in the same class.

Comment: but what do I do if I want access from both the same class and another class?

Comment: That's what the getLabel() method is for. You'd have to create an instance of Test. I recommend www.java-made-easy.com, it has the perfect tutorial for showing how to properly create a class and instances of the class for use outside of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Only use static methods or objects in any class (like `Clazz`) when you want to access them without creating an object (like `Clazz c = new Clazz();`). For instance, if I make a static method `public static void staticMethod() {}` and a regular method `public void regularMethod() {}`, this is how I access them:

```
public class Clazz //A class with methods
{
  public void regularMethod()
  {
    //Do something local
  }

  public static void staticMethod()
  {
    //Do something static
  }
}

public class Main //The main class with the main method.
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Clazz.staticMethod();

    Clazz c = new Clazz();

    c.regularMethod();
  }
}
```

Notice that I did not call `Clazz.regularMethod();`, because that is not possible. I did not call `c.staticMethod();` because that is poor form, even though it is possible.

All in all, try your best to NOT use static objects unless it (A) is absolutely necessary, or (B) has to be accessed at any time from any context